# Issue: Cannot reference -- The name 'Compeditors' does not exsist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, interface

Error: The name 'Compeditors' does not exsist in the current context

Newbie to MVC 4 and trying to get the complete right way to get it done.  With the MVC arch I am also using an interface. Everything was going great until I tried to code to add data to the database.  I have a view for the data add, the controller to accept the view and the model to get the data into the database as expected.  There are 2 Name Spaces. eManager.Core and eManager.Web2

Just tried everything I can think of, but the Compeditors collection cannot be found.. any ideas would be greatly apprtiated!!

```
//Compeditor Class in eManager.Core -- Compeditor.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;



namespace eManager.Core
{
    public class Compeditor
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int CompeditorId { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName  { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string MiddleInt { get; set; }
        public virtual string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        public virtual string State { get; set; }
        public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual string HomePhone { get; set; }
        public virtual string CellPhone { get; set; }
        public virtual int Height { get; set; }
        public virtual int Weight { get; set; }

    }
}

//DB Access Setup - BodyBuilderDB.cs  in eManager.Web2

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using eManager.Core;


namespace eManager.Web2.Infastructure
{
    public class BodyBuilderDB : System.Data.Entity.DbContext, IBodyBuilderDataSource
    {

        public BodyBuilderDB() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }


        public DbSet<Class_Type> Class_Types { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Compeditor> Compeditors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event_Class> Event_Classes { get; set; }


        IQueryable<Compeditor> IBodyBuilderDataSource.Compeditors
        {
            get
            { return Compeditors; }


        }

        IQueryable<Event_Class> IBodyBuilderDataSource.Event_Classes
        {
            get
            { return Event_Classes; }

        }

        IQueryable<Event> IBodyBuilderDataSource.Events
        {
            get
            { return Events; }

        }

        IQueryable<Class_Type> IBodyBuilderDataSource.Class_Types
        {
            get
            { return Class_Types; }

        }

        void IBodyBuilderDataSource.Save()
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}

//CompeditorController.cs -- Area I am having the issue in eManager.Web2
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using eManager.Core;
using eManager.Web2.Models;


namespace eManager.Web2.Controllers
{
    public class CompeditorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IBodyBuilderDataSource _db;
        public CompeditorController(IBodyBuilderDataSource db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new CreateCompeditorViewModel();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateCompeditorViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var compeditor = new Compeditor();

            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                compeditor.CompeditorId = viewModel.CompeditorId;
                compeditor.FirstName = viewModel.FirstName;
                compeditor.MiddleInt = viewModel.MiddleInt;
                compeditor.LastName = viewModel.LastName;
                compeditor.StreetAddress = viewModel.StreetAddress;
                compeditor.City = viewModel.City;
                compeditor.State = viewModel.State;
                compeditor.PostalCode = viewModel.PostalCode;
                compeditor.HomePhone = viewModel.HomePhone;
                compeditor.CellPhone = viewModel.CellPhone;
                compeditor.Height = viewModel.Height;
                compeditor.Weight = viewModel.Weight;
                compeditor.EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress;

                Compeditors.add(compeditor);  // "The name 'Compeditors' does not exsist in the current context

                _db.Save();

            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }


    }
}

//IBodyBuilderDataSource:  the Interface in eManager.Core
using eManager.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eManager.Core

{
    public interface IBodyBuilderDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Compeditor> Compeditors { get; }
        IQueryable<Event_Class> Event_Classes { get;  }
        IQueryable<Event> Events { get;  }
        IQueryable<Class_Type> Class_Types { get;  }
        void Save();
    }
}

//CreateCompeditorViewModel.cs -- View of the data add

using eManager.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eManager.Core

{
    public interface IBodyBuilderDataSource
    {
        IQueryable<Compeditor> Compeditors { get; }
        IQueryable<Event_Class> Event_Classes { get;  }
        IQueryable<Event> Events { get;  }
        IQueryable<Class_Type> Class_Types { get;  }
        void Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is probably the stupidest ever, but is it possible it's referred to correctly as `Competitors` in your DB and incorrectly as `Compeditors` in your code?

Comment: Not at all stupid.. I am know for a good single character typo once in a while.. I will check.

Comment: Well I did misspell it, but it appears to be correctly misspelled throughout all code.  Also, I cannot get intellisence to bring up anything referencing any of the calls in the Interface.  Although the interface is referenced in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You say your error is on this line (in your controller):

```
Compeditors.add(compeditor);
```

However, "Compeditors" is decalred in `BodyBuilderDB` (your `_db` field in your controller).  So probably what you want is:

```
_db.Compeditors.add(compeditor);
```

Comment: Yes this looks correct and does bring up Compeditors.. but now the 'add' will not intellisense or work.  Not sure how to get that operational?

Comment: here is the new error: Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable<eManager.Core.Compeditor>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<eManager.Core.Compeditor>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: well, yeah, C# is case-sensitive.  Since it appears you are using Entity Framework, the correct method name would be `Add` (capitalized).  Make sure you take advantage of your IDE -- when you type the `.` (dot) character after `Compeditors`, it will give you a drop-down list of all the potential members, including "Add".

Comment: Man I wish that was it, but I am trying to intellisense it and there is just no Add at all.. Is it possible that iQueryable does not have an Add component or ?

Comment: Correct, `IQueryable<T>` would not have an `Add` method, but `Compeditors` is declared as `DbSet<Compeditor>`, which *does* have such a method.

Comment: Ah, I see; your datasource interface declares them as `IQueryable`.  Why are you doing that?  They should be declared as `DbSet` if you want consumers to be able to add entities.  Frankly, I think the notion of using a "data source" abstraction provides absolutely no value when you're already using an ORM.

Comment: Ok.. Let me try and remove.. and thanks so much so far.  I'll let you know.  (Was going through training and instructed to use IQuerable)

Comment: No, the problem is `_db` is of type `IBodyBuilderDataSource`, which declares `Compeditors` as an `IQueryable<T>`, which does not have an `Add` method.  You can either **1)** Change the declaration in that interface to use a `DbSet<T>` instead or **2)** completely throw away the (IMO useless) datasource abstraction.